# PlantUML Getting Syntax Error (Flutter/Dart)

Tags: uml, plantuml

On the PlantUML I'm getting syntax errror on the class diagams generated by dcdg on Flutter/Dart. First error is on line 66, how to fix them? Planttext.com or plantuml-editor.kkeisuke.com can be used to show the uml.

```
@startuml
set namespaceSeparator ::

class "covid19stats::chartsData.dart::ChartsData" {
  +ChartData* total
  +ChartData* recovered
  +ChartData* deaths
  +ChartData* vaccine
}

"covid19stats::chartsData.dart::ChartsData" o-- "covid19stats::chartsData.dart::ChartData"

class "covid19stats::chartsData.dart::ChartData" {
  +bool* daily
  +bool* available
  +List<String*>* labels
  +List<int*>* values
  +List<Color*>* gradientColors
}

class "covid19stats::counter.dart::Counter" {
  +Animation<int*>* animation
  +TextStyle* textStyle
  +Widget* build()
}

"covid19stats::counter.dart::Counter" o-- "flutter::src::animation::animation.dart::Animation<int>"
"covid19stats::counter.dart::Counter" o-- "flutter::src::painting::text_style.dart::TextStyle"
"flutter::src::widgets::transitions.dart::AnimatedWidget" <|-- "covid19stats::counter.dart::Counter"

class "covid19stats::countryData.dart::CountryData" {
  +int* totalTests
  +int* testsPerMln
  +int* totalCases
  +double* casesPerMln
  +int* newCases
  +int* totalRecovered
  +int* newRecovered
  +int* activeCases
  +int* totalDeaths
  +double* deathsPerMln
  +int* criticalCases
  +int* newDeaths
  +String* link
  +int* vacTotal
  +int* vacDaily
  +int* vactotalPerHundred
  +int* vacdailyPerMillion
}

class "covid19stats::countryDataVac.dart::CountryDataVac" {
  +int* vacTotal
  +int* vacDaily
  +int* vactotalPerHundred
  +int* vacdailyPerMillion
  +String* date
  +Map<String*, dynamic>* toJson()
}

class "covid19stats::dateRangeDialog.dart::DateRangeDialog" {
  +DateTimeRange* availableRange
  +DateTimeRange* currentRange
  +_DateRangeDialogState* createState()
}

"covid19stats::dateRangeDialog.dart::DateRangeDialog" o-- "flutter::src::material::date.dart::DateTimeR
ange"
"flutter::src::widgets::framework.dart::StatefulWidget" <|-- "covid19stats::dateRangeDialog.dart::DateR
angeDialog"

class "covid19stats::dateRangeDialog.dart::_DateRangeDialogState" {
  +TextEditingController* fromController
  +TextEditingController* toController
  +DateFormat* dateFormat
  +DateTimeRange* selectedRange
  +int* selectedOption
  +DateTimeRange* preset7
  +DateTimeRange* preset28
  +void initState()
  +Widget* build()
  +void checkForPresets()
}

"covid19stats::dateRangeDialog.dart::_DateRangeDialogState" o-- "flutter::src::widgets::editable_text.d
art::TextEditingController"
"covid19stats::dateRangeDialog.dart::_DateRangeDialogState" o-- "intl::intl.dart::DateFormat"
"covid19stats::dateRangeDialog.dart::_DateRangeDialogState" o-- "flutter::src::material::date.dart::Dat
eTimeRange"
"flutter::src::widgets::framework.dart::State" <|-- "covid19stats::dateRangeDialog.dart::_DateRangeDial
ogState"

class "covid19stats::main.dart::MyApp" {
  +Widget* build()
}

"flutter::src::widgets::framework.dart::StatelessWidget" <|-- "covid19stats::main.dart::MyApp"

class "covid19stats::main.dart::MyHomePage" {
  +_MyHomePageState* createState()
}

"flutter::src::widgets::framework.dart::StatefulWidget" <|-- "covid19stats::main.dart::MyHomePage"

class "covid19stats::main.dart::_MyHomePageState" {
  -GlobalKey<State<StatefulWidget*>*>* _refreshIndicatorKey
  -GlobalKey<ScaffoldState*>* _scaffoldKey
  +Map<String*, CountryData*>* countryData
  +Map<String*, CountryDataVac*>* countryDataVac
  +Map<String*, ChartsData*>* chartsData
  +Map<String*, ChartsData*>* chartsDataVac
  +String* country
  +bool* justStarted
  +int* springAnimationDuration
  -AnimationController* _controller
  +ThemeData* datePickerTheme
  +DateTimeRange* selectedDateRange
  +Settings* settings
  +void initState()
  -void _triggerLiquidPullRefresh()
  +Future<void>* refreshData()
  +void dispose()
  +Widget* build()
  +dynamic navigateToSelection()
  +Future<void>* showDateDialog()
  +Future<void>* showSettingsDialog()
  +void checkRangeSetting()
  +Widget* createGraph()
}

"covid19stats::main.dart::_MyHomePageState" o-- "flutter::src::widgets::framework.dart::GlobalKey<State
<StatefulWidget>>"
"covid19stats::main.dart::_MyHomePageState" o-- "flutter::src::widgets::framework.dart::GlobalKey<Scaff
oldState>"
"covid19stats::main.dart::_MyHomePageState" o-- "flutter::src::animation::animation_controller.dart::An
imationController"
"covid19stats::main.dart::_MyHomePageState" o-- "flutter::src::material::theme_data.dart::ThemeData"
"covid19stats::main.dart::_MyHomePageState" o-- "flutter::src::material::date.dart::DateTimeRange"
"covid19stats::main.dart::_MyHomePageState" o-- "covid19stats::settingsDialog.dart::Settings"
"flutter::src::widgets::framework.dart::State" <|-- "covid19stats::main.dart::_MyHomePageState"
"flutter::src::widgets::ticker_provider.dart::TickerProviderStateMixin" <|-- "covid19stats::main.dart::
_MyHomePageState"

class "covid19stats::parser.dart::Parser" {
  {static} +CountryData* parseRow()
  {static} +CountryDataVac* parseRowVac()
  {static} +int* parseInteger()
  {static} +double* parseDouble()
  {static} +String* getInnerString()
  {static} +String* normalizeName()
  {static} +Map<String*, CountryData*>* getCountryData()
  {static} +String* capitalize()
  {static} +Map<String*, CountryDataVac*>* getCountryDataVac()
  {static} +List<String*>* getCategories()
  {static} +List<int*>* getDataPoints()
  {static} +List<String*>* getVacDates()
  {static} +List<int*>* getVacDataPoints()
  {static} +ChartsData* getChartsData()
}

class "covid19stats::selectCountry.dart::SelectionScreen" {
  +List<dynamic>* countries
  +String* selectedCountry
  +_SelectionScreenState* createState()
}

"flutter::src::widgets::framework.dart::StatefulWidget" <|-- "covid19stats::selectCountry.dart::Selecti
onScreen"

class "covid19stats::selectCountry.dart::_SelectionScreenState" {
  +ScrollController* scrollController
  +GlobalKey<State<StatefulWidget*>*>* key
  +Map<String*, String*>* countryFlags
  -TextEditingController* _controller
  +FocusNode* textFieldFocusNode
  +bool* searchFieldVisible
  +List<dynamic>* filteredCountries
  +bool* newSearch
  +void initState()
  +void dispose()
  +void toggleSearchField()
  +Widget* build()
  +Widget* getListTile()
}

"covid19stats::selectCountry.dart::_SelectionScreenState" o-- "flutter::src::widgets::scroll_controller
.dart::ScrollController"
"covid19stats::selectCountry.dart::_SelectionScreenState" o-- "flutter::src::widgets::framework.dart::G
lobalKey<State<StatefulWidget>>"
"covid19stats::selectCountry.dart::_SelectionScreenState" o-- "flutter::src::widgets::editable_text.dar
t::TextEditingController"
"covid19stats::selectCountry.dart::_SelectionScreenState" o-- "flutter::src::widgets::focus_manager.dar
t::FocusNode"
"flutter::src::widgets::framework.dart::State" <|-- "covid19stats::selectCountry.dart::_SelectionScreen
State"

class "covid19stats::settingsDialog.dart::Settings" {
  +bool* defaultDailyView
  +bool* alwaysLoadCharts
  +int* rangeSetting
  +bool* loaded
  +Future<void>* load()
  +Future<bool*>* save()
  +Settings* clone()
  +dynamic []()
}

class "covid19stats::settingsDialog.dart::SettingsDialog" {
  +Settings* settings
  +_SettingsDialogState* createState()
}

"covid19stats::settingsDialog.dart::SettingsDialog" o-- "covid19stats::settingsDialog.dart::Settings"
"flutter::src::widgets::framework.dart::StatefulWidget" <|-- "covid19stats::settingsDialog.dart::Settin
gsDialog"

class "covid19stats::settingsDialog.dart::_SettingsDialogState" {
  +Settings* newSettings
  +void initState()
  +Widget* build()
  +Row* getSwitchRow()
}

"covid19stats::settingsDialog.dart::_SettingsDialogState" o-- "covid19stats::settingsDialog.dart::Setti
ngs"
"flutter::src::widgets::framework.dart::State" <|-- "covid19stats::settingsDialog.dart::_SettingsDialog
State"

class "covid19stats::vaccineCountry.dart::VaccineCountry" {
  +String* country
  +List<Timeline*>* timeline
  +Map<String*, dynamic>* toJson()
}

class "covid19stats::vaccineCountry.dart::Timeline" {
  +int* total
  +int* daily
  +int* totalPerHundred
  +int* dailyPerMillion
  +String* date
  +Map<String*, dynamic>* toJson()
}

class "covid19stats::vaccineData.dart::VaccineData" {
  +int* total
  +int* daily
  +double* totalPerHundred
  +double* dailyPerMillion
  +String* link
}


@enduml
```

The first error:

[image: error]

‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the issue is caused by the fact that some strings are split over multiple lines (copy / past error or some automatic editor setting at 80(?) characters per line), i.e lines like:

```
"covid19stats::dateRangeDialog.dart::DateRangeDialog" o-- "flutter::src::material::date.dart::DateTimeR
ange"
"flutter::src::widgets::framework.dart::StatefulWidget" <|-- "covid19stats::dateRangeDialog.dart::DateR
angeDialog"
```

When correcting this, completely, to :

```
@startuml
set namespaceSeparator ::

class "covid19stats::chartsData.dart::ChartsData" {
  +ChartData* total
  +ChartData* recovered
  +ChartData* deaths
  +ChartData* vaccine
}

"covid19stats::chartsData.dart::ChartsData" o-- "covid19stats::chartsData.dart::ChartData"

class "covid19stats::chartsData.dart::ChartData" {
  +bool* daily
  +bool* available
  +List<String*>* labels
  +List<int*>* values
  +List<Color*>* gradientColors
}

class "covid19stats::counter.dart::Counter" {
  +Animation<int*>* animation
  +TextStyle* textStyle
  +Widget* build()
}

"covid19stats::counter.dart::Counter" o-- "flutter::src::animation::animation.dart::Animation<int>"
"covid19stats::counter.dart::Counter" o-- "flutter::src::painting::text_style.dart::TextStyle"
"flutter::src::widgets::transitions.dart::AnimatedWidget" <|-- "covid19stats::counter.dart::Counter"

class "covid19stats::countryData.dart::CountryData" {
  +int* totalTests
  +int* testsPerMln
  +int* totalCases
  +double* casesPerMln
  +int* newCases
  +int* totalRecovered
  +int* newRecovered
  +int* activeCases
  +int* totalDeaths
  +double* deathsPerMln
  +int* criticalCases
  +int* newDeaths
  +String* link
  +int* vacTotal
  +int* vacDaily
  +int* vactotalPerHundred
  +int* vacdailyPerMillion
}

class "covid19stats::countryDataVac.dart::CountryDataVac" {
  +int* vacTotal
  +int* vacDaily
  +int* vactotalPerHundred
  +int* vacdailyPerMillion
  +String* date
  +Map<String*, dynamic>* toJson()
}

class "covid19stats::dateRangeDialog.dart::DateRangeDialog" {
  +DateTimeRange* availableRange
  +DateTimeRange* currentRange
  +_DateRangeDialogState* createState()
}

"covid19stats::dateRangeDialog.dart::DateRangeDialog" o-- "flutter::src::material::date.dart::DateTimeRange"
"flutter::src::widgets::framework.dart::StatefulWidget" <|-- "covid19stats::dateRangeDialog.dart::DateRangeDialog"

class "covid19stats::dateRangeDialog.dart::_DateRangeDialogState" {
  +TextEditingController* fromController
  +TextEditingController* toController
  +DateFormat* dateFormat
  +DateTimeRange* selectedRange
  +int* selectedOption
  +DateTimeRange* preset7
  +DateTimeRange* preset28
  +void initState()
  +Widget* build()
  +void checkForPresets()
}

"covid19stats::dateRangeDialog.dart::_DateRangeDialogState" o-- "flutter::src::widgets::editable_text.dart::TextEditingController"
"covid19stats::dateRangeDialog.dart::_DateRangeDialogState" o-- "intl::intl.dart::DateFormat"
"covid19stats::dateRangeDialog.dart::_DateRangeDialogState" o-- "flutter::src::material::date.dart::DateTimeRange"
"flutter::src::widgets::framework.dart::State" <|-- "covid19stats::dateRangeDialog.dart::_DateRangeDialogState"

class "covid19stats::main.dart::MyApp" {
  +Widget* build()
}

"flutter::src::widgets::framework.dart::StatelessWidget" <|-- "covid19stats::main.dart::MyApp"

class "covid19stats::main.dart::MyHomePage" {
  +_MyHomePageState* createState()
}

"flutter::src::widgets::framework.dart::StatefulWidget" <|-- "covid19stats::main.dart::MyHomePage"

class "covid19stats::main.dart::_MyHomePageState" {
  -GlobalKey<State<StatefulWidget*>*>* _refreshIndicatorKey
  -GlobalKey<ScaffoldState*>* _scaffoldKey
  +Map<String*, CountryData*>* countryData
  +Map<String*, CountryDataVac*>* countryDataVac
  +Map<String*, ChartsData*>* chartsData
  +Map<String*, ChartsData*>* chartsDataVac
  +String* country
  +bool* justStarted
  +int* springAnimationDuration
  -AnimationController* _controller
  +ThemeData* datePickerTheme
  +DateTimeRange* selectedDateRange
  +Settings* settings
  +void initState()
  -void _triggerLiquidPullRefresh()
  +Future<void>* refreshData()
  +void dispose()
  +Widget* build()
  +dynamic navigateToSelection()
  +Future<void>* showDateDialog()
  +Future<void>* showSettingsDialog()
  +void checkRangeSetting()
  +Widget* createGraph()
}

"covid19stats::main.dart::_MyHomePageState" o-- "flutter::src::widgets::framework.dart::GlobalKey<State<StatefulWidget>>"
"covid19stats::main.dart::_MyHomePageState" o-- "flutter::src::widgets::framework.dart::GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>"
"covid19stats::main.dart::_MyHomePageState" o-- "flutter::src::animation::animation_controller.dart::AnimationController"
"covid19stats::main.dart::_MyHomePageState" o-- "flutter::src::material::theme_data.dart::ThemeData"
"covid19stats::main.dart::_MyHomePageState" o-- "flutter::src::material::date.dart::DateTimeRange"
"covid19stats::main.dart::_MyHomePageState" o-- "covid19stats::settingsDialog.dart::Settings"
"flutter::src::widgets::framework.dart::State" <|-- "covid19stats::main.dart::_MyHomePageState"
"flutter::src::widgets::ticker_provider.dart::TickerProviderStateMixin" <|-- "covid19stats::main.dart::_MyHomePageState"

class "covid19stats::parser.dart::Parser" {
  {static} +CountryData* parseRow()
  {static} +CountryDataVac* parseRowVac()
  {static} +int* parseInteger()
  {static} +double* parseDouble()
  {static} +String* getInnerString()
  {static} +String* normalizeName()
  {static} +Map<String*, CountryData*>* getCountryData()
  {static} +String* capitalize()
  {static} +Map<String*, CountryDataVac*>* getCountryDataVac()
  {static} +List<String*>* getCategories()
  {static} +List<int*>* getDataPoints()
  {static} +List<String*>* getVacDates()
  {static} +List<int*>* getVacDataPoints()
  {static} +ChartsData* getChartsData()
}

class "covid19stats::selectCountry.dart::SelectionScreen" {
  +List<dynamic>* countries
  +String* selectedCountry
  +_SelectionScreenState* createState()
}

"flutter::src::widgets::framework.dart::StatefulWidget" <|-- "covid19stats::selectCountry.dart::SelectionScreen"

class "covid19stats::selectCountry.dart::_SelectionScreenState" {
  +ScrollController* scrollController
  +GlobalKey<State<StatefulWidget*>*>* key
  +Map<String*, String*>* countryFlags
  -TextEditingController* _controller
  +FocusNode* textFieldFocusNode
  +bool* searchFieldVisible
  +List<dynamic>* filteredCountries
  +bool* newSearch
  +void initState()
  +void dispose()
  +void toggleSearchField()
  +Widget* build()
  +Widget* getListTile()
}

"covid19stats::selectCountry.dart::_SelectionScreenState" o-- "flutter::src::widgets::scroll_controller.dart::ScrollController"
"covid19stats::selectCountry.dart::_SelectionScreenState" o-- "flutter::src::widgets::framework.dart::GlobalKey<State<StatefulWidget>>"
"covid19stats::selectCountry.dart::_SelectionScreenState" o-- "flutter::src::widgets::editable_text.dart::TextEditingController"
"covid19stats::selectCountry.dart::_SelectionScreenState" o-- "flutter::src::widgets::focus_manager.dart::FocusNode"
"flutter::src::widgets::framework.dart::State" <|-- "covid19stats::selectCountry.dart::_SelectionScreenState"

class "covid19stats::settingsDialog.dart::Settings" {
  +bool* defaultDailyView
  +bool* alwaysLoadCharts
  +int* rangeSetting
  +bool* loaded
  +Future<void>* load()
  +Future<bool*>* save()
  +Settings* clone()
  +dynamic []()
}

class "covid19stats::settingsDialog.dart::SettingsDialog" {
  +Settings* settings
  +_SettingsDialogState* createState()
}

"covid19stats::settingsDialog.dart::SettingsDialog" o-- "covid19stats::settingsDialog.dart::Settings"
"flutter::src::widgets::framework.dart::StatefulWidget" <|-- "covid19stats::settingsDialog.dart::SettingsDialog"

class "covid19stats::settingsDialog.dart::_SettingsDialogState" {
  +Settings* newSettings
  +void initState()
  +Widget* build()
  +Row* getSwitchRow()
}

"covid19stats::settingsDialog.dart::_SettingsDialogState" o-- "covid19stats::settingsDialog.dart::Settings"
"flutter::src::widgets::framework.dart::State" <|-- "covid19stats::settingsDialog.dart::_SettingsDialogState"

class "covid19stats::vaccineCountry.dart::VaccineCountry" {
  +String* country
  +List<Timeline*>* timeline
  +Map<String*, dynamic>* toJson()
}

class "covid19stats::vaccineCountry.dart::Timeline" {
  +int* total
  +int* daily
  +int* totalPerHundred
  +int* dailyPerMillion
  +String* date
  +Map<String*, dynamic>* toJson()
}

class "covid19stats::vaccineData.dart::VaccineData" {
  +int* total
  +int* daily
  +double* totalPerHundred
  +double* dailyPerMillion
  +String* link
}
@enduml
```

It all works as expected, see also this [plantUML diagram](http://www.plantuml.com/plantuml/uml/nLbTR-Cs5dtthn3yj9lPBB3xqjO8WXaapSoqawaH1-b3KHWCUIspeKcLlB8ddSv_hqXVYn8ZUQmQHbyCy_2Gz_3ZVaXwxP1PB5Tgv00ppLRW2iPX1WMp38tD9fFHY2lcN3RcPYt5_xvpoD1D9dp9BBfhXko_eletcLpLm3ZxFCgoLm7mxRCC3JALO1Qg2S62I70139Sk0TUCSwbXz6Kq6gB3d9yVfZlG1wsqiT17OrIbcqdr79jiNRNPem8FVP0EBsPefSxFBi-o2WVbwWwfqQDhfag8w9LHndeyjqn8q1W0vxUWMwOfDOBTQTosIE4RBLSCfT4xMsm7-Dvx-8GpV5PG7TJkhyT_bY87FCiUIwd4l_xjBHzYaxPzeKgiMfE9itmogGqs_jAmbhZByT-tKJ2fKUfyCl7Bc3k_3XfMBt4yIWPj_2Az7RHCE-brk9Om4Djz66SNVtgRXwZRTqJskNcL8a979JMIlzo3GnSXtvg2lLMwJRjY3W9DcFBHdo7tGCBKiAbvSUXTTC78UmaoZd8D7UEloLMZRU6Hr3Yt4YMFIcjJSJpvHgQaVY96SFfxRwO9N9ENrK0GKXbyLseHHCUku95UYrJAN_KlNp-M1yRJamaW7Sv9P3MMBnY2Rz-oueAm_sJYMRELv9T-qtzmHWTFx5w97t_7T0xNaYcJqrAksoYjnQFtShNjYV5gs-uWyD9Qq5XtpvDfPyZGqommXD288MEun0xtzhveg-xj775W5Ddlt0lBLh0nzec61NsBKgMkFLpfe9Fet3D_7XI5lnVI1x0hez4QfS2UPGjhLh6zXuYcJVEcRenTCGptYlvt7Am31Hn1X2PTr8Z-L52QI8SL5XpWDxqz___MTwsD59dK4kb6TEILciQNm9ygcTCmtj7rEM9VwH9rtWWG4lrrd_jSGTDqxkpuU0bIOtLh_I-HuzaSE_lflOISumYPFIwoObBJkDldDqL1Vj1HTGpIgy2vRhVkDdkGl7Tc1LEM0scSHwGtx1qVYVPBEK1t8fFKdxzLvf6f7-7v8g0NRGbdbxv0d5jOM73Bzrf8pj3OYfwCvMonC4g4qM688yHJqoJMIAUUosEpanepRyskaHS3OiKVo7NhO29DIZmorwZbVokTZryM6udS5PvSrwxNfTtLq-Srs0pFSzuEuajOGL0IWlDKyYUm0TmJeMll2ce1VQ1oLJVzwuctvm6RevLv3lQ3_BsKObegTRSzuMq0lYcnj73XgTNMqE5xVOtuBAGhZEiFubIeP9gjPUvNO6P1k3IwouXRcarbWK957sEtJ68bsIBi1b5QkiWXtrfMBCaX1xW9nTM377Y_DrrUZazjEVN5OorsFwmrxYzDrN7DZxOSinTwNvYB-AXKUynm8uDJv70J2T-rRYsDd15uV0BUhwX_VWnXPbvOFrLzaFS1dH8OfhYLdwGUQBW_qnVCkjhQD3IsgUYp9qZ-9NlLp0zPuD-PZVVeX1FJGAHLZOGfDLBtUusGWsttq-CgKQv3eyM8kI07VAyrs6sxXwHzAQVa7_2HhTA9-hDWcBo1z4pEMI4np9uGzYRDTF9qZz9tKe7E479Z9RWkgjH8F3_Vr5HjzzKfAxCLktV2oEgTC-RiG8tDFO_1stn9gw-TZrBHZ5i07UuV2Q6yLHSQ4bmi1sBsfVb2_PVCTfeYSFYY1kn7vn9eLoh4ADMiNbo2UDOXPUHJHob8Vs9TTwDOA5xEq-UlxjBfnl3IVJI2NbVUI52YncBHve1PlWoz3zB9HmKT1xwG2i7IsTB1qtWDcrcOehEiIckYYA39SmMpQBsdNefGzUDbtKkrkpR3Z--0yc5xXY_pU7hQunFP7ruu7Q_Z-2V_Kso4lwpp5TCihm-Xli375mU3X5B465I_j3zxm8AL2iCBq0S9czZ3r8Ozkm-6YH2quvjVsoZQ8rrLH10l7m8ytdeu2FIgmx4r-Lry5EBAQ6W_ZVpoAsMAmUkChqjx7xVcRMvl7XXkTNXLUNos6IXno9vsRLIwio7aKcF0kyEg0WmnTBQHo9TLY_PykAf_hfuVeAzls-aJQTlf7rgWt_2kznoK5ltZZwhOthcG_X_nDQ9RqSx8YyzTTKkqlgNqVKWvuLSKqjtuJFSGaGDqqzD5AZrszQkdJs2LjDUWHRbIVm40)

Comment: ohh it's due to split copy from android studio, is there any way to prevent this? thanks so much.

Comment: I have no idea whether this is possible, but check he settings of the program where you "Copy" from and the settings of the program where you "Paste" to.

Comment: @osunkaya perhaps it's the console that is hard-wrapping this output? Maybe make the console window wider (assuming the code is getting printed there before you copy it)?